# What are the upgrade steps for MediatR Dependency Injection

Tags: mediatr

I took Jimmy's course which used MediatR DI 1.0.1. I'm trying to upgrade a project based on that course's examples to 2.0.0 but I can't find any upgrade steps.

Here's a specific example from the course. I've changed IAsyncRequest to IRequest and that appears to be correct. The errors remaining are for:

```
public class EmployeeEditHandler : AsyncRequestHandler<EmployeeEditModel>
```

and

```
protected override async Task HandleCore(EmployeeEditModel message)
```

What should AsyncRequestHandler be changed to? does HandleCore need to be changed?

```
namespace EmployeeDirectory.ViewModels
{
    using MediatR;
    //Other using statements removed for this example

    public class EmployeeEditQuery : IAsyncRequest<EmployeeEditModel>
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmployeeEditModel : IAsyncRequest
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmployeeEditQueryHandler 
        : IAsyncRequestHandler<EmployeeEditQuery, EmployeeEditModel>
    {
        private readonly DirectoryContext _dbContext;

        public EmployeeEditQueryHandler(DirectoryContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }
        public async Task<EmployeeEditModel> Handle(EmployeeEditQuery message)
        {
            var model = await _dbContext
                .Employees
                .Where(e => e.Id == message.Id)
                .ProjectTo<EmployeeEditModel>()
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

            return model;
        }
    }

    public class EmployeeEditHandler : AsyncRequestHandler<EmployeeEditModel>
    {
        private readonly DirectoryContext _dbContext;

        public EmployeeEditHandler(DirectoryContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        protected override async Task HandleCore(EmployeeEditModel message)
        {
            var employee = await _dbContext.Employees
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == message.Id);

            Mapper.Map(message, employee);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found Jimmy's rewrite of Contoso using MediatR 2.0.0 that gave me the answer. Here are the changes I had to make to go from 1.0.1 to 2.0.0:

Update controller actions:
From: await _mediator.SendAsync(query);
To: await _mediator.Send(query);

Update AsyncRequestHandler:
From: public class EmployeeEditHandler : AsyncRequestHandler
To: public class EmployeeEditHandler : IAsyncRequestHandler

Update HandleCore:
From: protected override async Task HandleCore(EmployeeEditModel message)
To: public async Task Handle(EmployeeEditModel message)

Update IAsyncRequest:
From: public class EmployeeEditQuery : IAsyncRequest
To: public class EmployeeEditQuery : IRequest